# Function like macros

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

Is this valid C code:

foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_

#define FUNC(var)   \
   do               \
   {                \
      //something  \
   }while(0)        \

#endif
```

foo.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

FUNC(5); //How is it possible to call the function-like macro from here?

int main(void)
{
   //do something
   return 0;
}
```

I have some (working) code that is arranged like this, and in global scope calling a function-like macro. How is this possible?

Comment: [It does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/TT5d5GGbv).

Comment: There is no mystery , just replace the text 'FUNC(5)' by the expanded macro. You will see it's invalid c code

Comment: I know the above code doesn't compile, but I have some other code I'm working on that has the above, a function like macro in a header file and calling it in a C file and it works. Its an embedded system

Comment: You asked if it was valid. It does not compile because it is not valid.

Comment: Re “… I have some other code…”: Generally it helps to ask about the code that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have some (working) code that is arranged like this, and in global scope calling a function-like macro. How is this possible?

There is nothing *inherently* wrong with a function-like macro being invoked at file scope.  It's all a question of the macro's replacement text, in light of its arguments.  The function-like macro you present in the question cannot be invoked at file scope because it expands to a `do` / `while` statement, and those must appear inside functions.  Whatever example you are thinking of that works cannot have the same kind of replacement text.

Here's an example demonstrating a function-like macro that can be expanded at file scope:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DECL_INT(v,i) int v = (i)

DECL_INT(var, 42);

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", var);
}
```

That means exactly the same thing as ...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int var = (42);

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", var);
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, Thanks for the explanation!
It works if I remove the loop

Answer (score 1):

The compiler shall issue an error message because you may place only declarations in a file scope. You may not place a do-while statement.

This macro

```
FUNC(5);
```

is just substituted for this do while statement by the preprocessor in the file scope or where the macro is placed

```
do 
{
   //something
}while(0);
```

It seems you extracted  an incomplete code snippet.

To make the code valid you need to place this macro FUNC(5); in a function definition.

Comment: No it compiles if I remove the line "FUNC(5);"

Comment: @Bei: So the code that is not valid C code is valid C code if you remove the invalid part? What is your question?

Comment: @Bei It seems you do not understand what you are writing. I have pointed in my answer that the provided code in your question is incorrect.

Comment: Missunderstood Vlads answer

Comment: Ok, so there must be some kind of code that can make it work. What needs to be done in the header file to be able to call the define from global scope in the main.c?

Comment: @Bei You can place the macro FUNC(5); inside a function definition.

Comment: I know, but that's not how the code is written in the platform I'm working with.
Just curious how it's possible that the code is working.

Comment: @Bei: Show the code!

Comment: Ok now I understand, the macro just replaces the "call". I missed it in the original code, there was no loop. Sorry and thanks for clarifying